# ¿Cómo usar Observable para crear una pausa?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Estoy usando un observable para crear una pausa de 1 segundo, luego mostrar una alerta y cancelar la suscripción. Pero no se realiza la pausa.

Este es el código que estoy usando:

```
     let obj =   Observable.interval(1000).subscribe(()=>{});
      alert("tiempo finalizado");
      obj.unsubscribe();
```

Answer (score 1):

El alert tiene que ir dentro del callback del observable.

Así:

```
let obj =   Observable.interval(1000).subscribe(()=>{
            alert("tiempo finalizado");
});

  obj.unsubscribe();
```